# How to show title of gitk instance in application switcher?

Tags: 20.04, git, application-switcher

I usually have multiple instances of [Gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk) open while working on projects. When I switch between Gitk windows I cannot see which Gitk instance belongs to which project, though.

[image: GitK in application switcher]

The project title is written in the header of the window once have it in foreground.

Is it possible to show the window title in the application switcher?

Comment: How do you manage to have these instances have separate icons on the launcher? Typically, different instances would appear under the same icon, and then you could cycle between the windows with Alt+Key_above_tab, which shows a thumbnail and the window title.

Answer (score 2):

Check if using
<Super>+<Tab>
instead of
<Alt>+<Tab>
is useful for you.

If so, that can be configured in *Settings* -> *Keyboard Shortcuts* (*Switch windows* vs. *Switch applications*).

[image]

Besides, a couple of possibly useful links, which may even be interesting as replacement features from what you have in mind:

1. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/302/windowoverlay-icons/
2. https://github.com/daniellandau/switcher

Comment: it's *Settings->Devices->Keyboard* but otherwise this should work for OP

Comment: @RobertRiedl - That's how I see it, see EDITed answer.

Comment: huh, seems to depend on the Ubuntu version ? anyway, your screenshot made it quite clear

Comment: "Switch windows" actually shows the project name. Thanks. The only drawback is that it only shows the gitk windows of the **current** virtual desktop while "Switch applications" shows all gitk windows of **all** desktops. Do you know how to change this?

Comment: @JJD - No, I don't know.
I guess that would be actually defeating the (main) purpose of having virtual desktops.

Answer (score 1):

Since gitk is a friendly wish (Tcl/Tk) program, we can utilize wish's options to do what you want manually. There might be a way to edit /usr/bin/gitk to do exactly what you want, but I have found an alternative.

### Method:

```
cd ./dir-with-git-repo/
wish /usr/bin/gitk -name "Manual Name"
```

### Result:

Application Switcher now shows gitk icon instance with "Manual Name" as application name.

### Alt Method:

Edit /usr/bin/gitk line 3:

```
exec wish "$0" -- "$@"
```

to

```
exec wish "$0" -name "$@" -- "$@"
```

### Alt Result:

"$ gitk" shows -- for gitk application name
"$ gitk branchname" shows branchname for gitk application name in switcher.

Comment: `gitk <branchname>` works. Thanks. But I mostly start `gitk --all > /dev/null 2>&1 &`. It would be useful if in this case the name of the repository is shown.